# backbone.js Can't find error in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I'm new to javascript and backbone.js
I want to create simple web page with 10 squares with form that will take square id and color.

So every square must have its own style in CSS.

I tried to make it with 10 templates. But script doesn't work at all.

Here is my code:

```
alert("script entry");

$(function () {


blocks = [
            {number: "1", state: "block1" },
            {number: "2", state: "block2" },
            {number: "3", state: "block3" },
            {number: "4", state: "block4" },
            {number: "5", state: "block5" },
            {number: "6", state: "block6" },
            {number: "7", state: "block7" },
            {number: "8", state: "block8" },
            {number: "9", state: "block9" },
            {number: "10", state: "block10" },
];

var BlockModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    defaults:{
        "state": "block1",
        "number": "1"
    }
});
var BlockCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: BlockModel,
});
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection([  
           model:BlockModel
            ]);

var BlockView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "blockTag",
    className: "blockClass",
    templates: { 
        "block1": _.template($('#block1').html()),
        "block2": _.template($('#block2').html()),
        "block3": _.template($('#block3').html()),
        "block4": _.template($('#block4').html()),
        "block5": _.template($('#block5').html()),
        "block6": _.template($('#block6').html()),
        "block7": _.template($('#block7').html()),
        "block8": _.template($('#block8').html()),
        "block9": _.template($('#block9').html()),
        "block10": _.template($('#block10').html())
    },

    render: function () {
        var state= this.model.get("state");  
        var tmpl = this.templates(state); 
        $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON())); 
        return this;
    }
});



var appView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#block"), //большой контейнер

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new blockNumbers(blocks);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){ 

         _.each(this.collection.models, function () {
            that.renderBlock(this.model);
        }, this);
    },

     renderBlock: function (inputModel) {
        var blockView = new BlockView({
            {model: inputModel}
        });
        this.$el.append(blockView.render().el);
    }


}); 

var app = new appView();


});
```

Where is my error? 
My `index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">



</head>
 <body>

    <div id="block"> 



<script type="text/template" id="block1">
  <div class="block1"><%=number%></div>
  <div class="buttonplace">
        <input type="button" value="check" />
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block2">
   <div class="block2"><%=number%></div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block3">
  <div class="block3">3</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block4">
  <div class="block4">4</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block5">
  <div class="block5">5</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block6">
  <div class="block6">6</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block7">
  <div class="block7">7</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block8">
  <div class="block8">8</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block9">
  <div class="block9">9</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block10">
  <div class="block10">10</div>

</script>


</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Nothing but script doesn't run

Comment: @Jack pointed out (beat me to it ;-)) some good things that might help you. Also, you might want to have a look at this TODO example. Might enlighten you on some techniques... http://jsfiddle.net/icoxfog417/pfxP5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
templates: { 
    "block1": _.template($('#block1').html()),
    ...         
    "block10": _.template($('#block10').html())
},
```

you have defined an object above.

```
var tmpl = this.templates(state);
```

but you call it as a function.

you may get the templates as `this.templates[state];`

**UPDATE**

I think you can just use the same template as:

```
<script type="text/template" id="block">
    <div class="block<%=number%>"><%=number%></div>
    <div class="buttonplace">
        <input type="button" value="check" />
  </div>
</script>
```

and you can simplfy your model like this, too.

Of course, if you need.

**UPDATE**

You may `new` a Collection with some options out of single `{}` but not `[]` or more `{}`s, like this:

```
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection({  
    model:BlockModel
});

...

var blockView = new BlockView({
   model: inputModel
});
```

not:

```
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection([  
    model:BlockModel
]);

...

var blockView = new BlockView({
   {model: inputModel}
});
```

**UPDATE**

the `blockNumbers` is an instance of Collection, you can't fetch data for it by `new` like:

```
this.collection = new blockNumbers(blocks);
```

You should assign the `bolckNumbers` to `this.collection`, and give it an url , then call `sync()` or `fetch()` to get the data, then render it.

**END**

Lastly, I have found too much mistake of basics above, **Backbone.js** is simple but hard, you ought to be able to solve it yourself, it is useful to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, primarily you are using parentheses in some cases instead of brackets `[` and instead of curly braces `{`. You also have some extra trailing commas. Further in your HTML your closing tag for the *block* div should be before all your script templates.

For example

```
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection([  
           model:BlockModel
            ]);
```

Should be

```
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection({  
           model:BlockModel
       });
```

And

```
var tmpl = this.templates(state);
```

Should be

```
 var tmpl = this.templates[state];
```

In addition in your appView you are trying to instantiate a new instance of your instance

```
this.collection = new blockNumbers(blocks);
```

While you probably meant to do

```
this.collection = new BlockNumbers(blocks);
```

Here's a working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fewiqedo/1/)

Aside from all that you have a lot of repetition with your templates, you can really consolidate them all into one or two templates.

For example you can just have one template for blocks with a button and one for blocks without a button and update the blocks state accordingly

```
  <script type="text/template" id="blockWithButton">
  <div class="block<%=number%>"><%=number%></div>
  <div class="buttonplace">
        <input type="button" value="check" />
  </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/template" id="blockWithoutButton">
  <div class="block<%=number%>"><%=number%></div>
  </script>
```

Another [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fewiqedo/2/)